# What are some good resources to learn about Hilbert spaces corresponding to QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, resource-recommendations

I want to deepen my understanding about Hilbert spaces corresponding to QFT. Could you please introduce some good resources?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/best-book-to-learn-more-about-quantum-mechanics.730321/

Comment: spaFor non-interacting fields they are Fock space. For interacting fields, they have been constructed for 1+1 D theories, but not explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

For say a real scalar Bosonic QFT in $d$ dimensional flat spacetime, I believe that regardless of interacting or not, the Hilbert space should be $\mathcal{H}=L^2(\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{d-1}),d\nu)$. Here $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{d-1})$ is the space of real-valued Schwartz temperate distributions. The measure $\nu$ is a Borel probability measure on $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{d-1})$.

In case the Euclidean path integral can be realized as integration with respect to an honest probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ and if one has the so-called Markov property, then one should be able to get $\nu$ as follows. One must show that for $\mu$-almost all $\phi\in\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ one can define the restriction of $\phi(\tau,x_1,\ldots,x_{d-1})$ to the $\tau=0$ hyperplane. Here $\tau$ is the Euclidean or imaginary time, while $x_1,\ldots,x_{d-1}$ are the spatial coordinates. Then this restriction operation gives a Borel-measurable map $R: \mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{d})\rightarrow\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{d-1})$ and $\nu$ is just the push-forward measure $R_{\ast}\mu$, namely the law of the time zero restriction.

This can be done rather explicitly for the free field while recovering the isomorphism of $\mathcal{H}$ with Fock space. See:

1. J. Glimm and A. Jaffe, *Quantum Physics*, 2nd ed., Springer-Verlag, New York, 1987
2. B. Simon, *The $P(\phi)_2$ Euclidean (Quantum) Field Theory*, Princeton University Press, Princeton, N.J., 1974. Princeton Series in Physics.
3. A. Klein, "The semigroup characterization of Osterwalder-Schrader path spaces and the construction of Euclidean fields", J. Funct. Analysis, vol. 27, no. 3, pp. 277-291, 1978.

Comment: If we consider lattice quantum field theory, the Hilbert space corresponding to each site is L^2(R). Now, for the whole system we have a tensor product of L^2(R). what happens when we take the continuum limit?

Comment: On an infinite lattice like $\mathbb{Z}^d$, the Hilbert space would be $L^2(s'(\mathbb{Z}^{d-1}),d\nu)$ where $s'(\mathbb{Z}^{d-1})$ is the space of lattice fields with at most polynomial growth at infinity. I don't think it is a good idea to try to realize this as an infinite tensor product of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$'s. You can map these discrete spaces into distributions on the continuum. When you do a continuum limit, you have weak convergence of a sequence of probability measures...

Comment: ...You can learn about that at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362040/reformulation-construction-of-thermodynamic-limit-for-gff/362118#362118  and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364470/a-set-of-questions-on-continuous-gaussian-free-fields-gff/365144#365144 on the example of the free field, in order to get the conceptual picture right.