# Hilbert space of free theory vs interacting theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, interactions

In view of [Haag's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haag%27s_theorem), it seems the Hilbert spaces of a free theory and an interacting theory are not the same. Though it seems very believable, I could not find a result that states that this is the case for all theories.

Intuitively, it seems obvious that the Hilbert space of an interacting theory involving distinct fields is not the same as any of the Hilbert spaces of the individual free theories. However, what if we consider the scalar field with $\phi^4$ interactions? In this case I was unable to convince myself that the Hilbert space of the interacting theory must be different than the Hilbert space of the free $\phi$ field.

Is it always the case that Hilbert space of an interacting theory is different than any free theory?

Comment: Have you read the proof (http://gymarkiv.sdu.dk/MFM/kdvs/mfm%2030-39/mfm-31-5.pdf)? It applies to any theory of a single neutral scalar which means $\phi(x)$ and its conjugate momentum must transform irreducibly under translation and rotations.

Comment: Without any offense to theorists... but has anybody actually observed a free field? I am not aware that such a thing exists in this universe, except on paper. Is this theorem mathematics' hint that we shouldn't be hunting for the snark, even on paper?

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thank you! I will take a look at that paper. Sorry about my ignorance, but what is the consequence of $\phi$ and its conjugate momentum having to transform irreducibly under translation and rotations?

Comment: @FlatterMann I come from mathematics so I find the math itself quite interesting, even if the physical implications are not great (or even observable).

Comment: @CBBAM There is nothing wrong with your question. My point is simply that mathematics sometimes gives very subtle hints to physicists about the underlying physical concepts (like, in this case, possibly about the existence of "free" fields). While we would love to understand the world in simple terms (like systems that are free of self-interaction), this may not be possible in an absolute sense. It is, of course, a very good approximation for many systems (like the em field at optical energies), but that doesn't mean this approximation can be universally extended. Nature certainly doesn't.

Comment: Irreducibility is what ensures that two unitarily equivalent theories will have generators of translations and rotations that are also unitarily equivalent. This is needed to produce the contradiction of free and interacting Wightman functions being equal if we assume the Hilbert spaces are the same.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thanks, it is quite interesting that one can rigorously show that the two Hilbert spaces cannot be the same. Aside from the paper you linked, are there any resources you recommend to learn more about mathematically rigorous QFT (e.g. in the spirit of the Wightman axioms)?

Comment: @ConnorBehan What exactly do you mean with "the Hilbert spacing being the same" or "not the same"? - there is always a unitary map from one to the other; do you instead mean that both (irreducible) representations are unitary inequivalent?

Comment: Right. It's just unitary equivalence which gets you the equal Wightman functions.

Comment: I gave a brief description of the Hilbert space in this other answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/633835/ in that point of view Haag's theorem has to do with the measures not being absolutely continuous with respect to each other. A baby version of this issue is what happens when taking infinite products of measures https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakutani%27s_theorem_(measure_theory)

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Thank you for the links!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the Hilbert space for a free theory and an interacting theory are different.  There can not exist a unitary isomorphism that preserves the algebra of operators.  (You need the caveat about preserving the algebra of operators, because all separable Hilbert spaces are unitarily isomorphic in many ways.)

In fact, Haag's theorem implies something stronger:  any change in any one of the coupling constants gives rise to a different Hilbert space.  So, not only do free & interacting theories get different Hilbert spaces, but also you get different Hilbert spaces for different values of the coupling constants $g \neq g'$.  Even crazier, this is true of the quadratic coupling constants, aka, the mass terms.   Different masses lead to different state spaces, even in free theories.